# Is it commonplace, or good form, to use summary columns in a database table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I need some advice from the database people here.  If I have this database table:

```
EVENT
Id
Name
StartDateTime
EndDateTime
```

Would it be ok to include a summary column in the table that would contain the duration of the event in seconds (seconds between StartDateTime and EndDateTime):

```
EVENT
Id
Name
StartDateTime
EndDateTime
DurationInSeconds  <---
```

I know this will require extra storage space, but as the table gets extremely large (tens of millions of rows), it will become quite expensive to calculate this duration at runtime.

I want to follow "best practices", but also don't want to make the data unusable due to not having it in an "inexpensive" format (performance wise).

What would you do?

---

If it matters, I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Sure this makes sense. Even better would be to make a persisted computed column. That way it will calculate the value when the data changes and you don't need to calculate it all the time. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx

Comment: It only depends on the usage. If you are going to do heavy searching on it perhaps you could store it.

Comment: Are you consider use an index?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a computed column with your sample information.

```
create table MyEvents
(
    ID int
    , Name varchar(20)
    , StartDateTime datetime
    , EndDateTime datetime
    , DurationInSeconds as datediff(second, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) PERSISTED
)


insert MyEvents
select 1
    , 'Event 1'
    , getdate()
    , dateadd(minute, 3, getdate())

select * 
from MyEvents
```

Answer (score 1):

The term "best practices" is overused when it comes to database design.  The problem is that for many people, "best practices" amounts to "doing what the smart people do" instead of learning what the smart people learn.

For any significant design problem, there will be multiple satisfactory designs, although some will be more satisfactory than others.  In your case, it won't be a disaster either way.  The differences in storage space and processing time will be small, in the larger scheme of things.  What will work best for you depends on your use of the data, as several comments have pointed out.

Here are a couple of things to watch out for.

If you store duration time as a separate column, you run the risk that some careless updater will change the end-time of an event, and forget to change the duration accordingly.  This is unlikely to happen in a well programmed application, but if you have occasional fixups through interactive SQL, a cockpit error could introduce this kind of inconsistency.

If you calculate the duration at retrieval time, and if a lot of different programmers code this calculation, you run the risk that one of them will not know how to calculate the difference between two timestamps.

Probably the best compromise is the calculated column.  However, it could turn out to be best to store start time and duration, and let end time be the calculated value.  Again, it depends on what you do with the data.